# Silverstripe 3.4 temporary Page depending on Date

Tags: redirect, infinite-loop, silverstripe

I'd like to show my TempPage depending on a StartDate and EndDate.

I manage this with function canView.

"return false" in the last if-Statement gets me to my LoginPage.

Controller::curr()->redirect(Director::baseURL()) results in an endless loop.

> Whats the right syntax to redirect to Homepage (home) without ending
>   in a loop?

```
    class TempPage extends Page {

public function canView($Member = null){
    $now  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if(Permission::checkMember($Member, 'CMS_ACCESS')){
        return true;
    }elseif($now > $this->StartDate &&  $now < $this->EndDate){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
        Controller::curr()->redirect(Director::baseURL());
    }
}
```

Comment: In general I would recommended looking over github.com/silverstripe-scienceninjas/embargoexpiry for "show my ... depending on a StartDate and EndDate", for the specfic "Controller::curr()->redirect(Director::baseURL()) results in an endless loop" this would be best debugged as there is a lot of information missing : what url is being requested? what is "home"? is .htaccess standard? etc... I would instead redirect to 404... return $this->httpError(404, "Not Found"); or create a specfic page for "temp page not available due to date"

Comment: redirect won't work after you returned false in the else clause. This kind of bug is easy to find using a proper step debugger like xdebug.

Comment: @wkm: if you read my question attentive, you see that it is about redirecting to Homepage (BaseUrl). return false redirects to Login. Its clear, after a return false, nothing happens. But as also mentioned in my question 'Controller::curr()->.....' generates a loop. I tried both; each for its own.

Comment: What should be clear: TempPage should be visible in the CMS, but invisible in the navigation on fronted if date is out of range. Thats why i called it TempPage.